# fetch call gives error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, native

when fetch call is used i am getting the following error! please help to figure out !

```
componentDidMount() {
      url = "api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather? 
      lat=37.422&lon=-122.084&appid="+API_KEY;
      fetch(url)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
    })
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Does it work if you put the `url` on one single line? `url = "api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=37.422&lon=-122.084&appid="+API_KEY;`

Comment: You may want to add which operating system you are trying to running the code on. It look like android.

Comment: @Tholle yeah its just that the line wrapped its in one line

Comment: Are you sure these lines are causing the redbox? Removing them the app runs?

Comment: `url = "api.openweathermap.org/.....` - so this is calling **your** server - should it be calling openweathermap? consider using `url = "//api.openweathermap.org/.....`